# POST request via libcurl is failing

Tags: curl, libcurl

curl https://connect.insteon.com/api/v2/commands \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authentication: APIKey $API_KEY" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
--data-binary '{"command":"on","level":75,"device_id":67890}'

This is the curl command to control insteon devices and it is perfectly working fine in linux machine via terminal.

I was trying to run the same using CURL commands but it is throwing error.
If someone can help me in sending above request in curl command format it would be of great help.

Snippet:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://connect.insteon.com/api/v2/commands");

 list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json");

 list = curl_slist_append(list,"Authentication: APIKey XXXXXX");

 list = curl_slist_append(list,"Authorization: Bearer XXXXX");

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

/*I tried both PUT and POST as well*/

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); /* !!! */

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"--data-binary '{\"command\":\"on\",\"level\":75,\"device_id\":738486}'"); /* data goes here */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
            curl_easy_strerror(res);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Comment: Please add the snippet anyway

Comment: The CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST serves no purpose there. POSTFIELDS imply a POST already.

Comment: "it is throwing error" ? What error exactly?

Comment: Hi there is no error in linux machine however when i ported same code in windows machine curl_easy_perform(curl); is returning CURLE_SSL_CACERT. i haven't debugged it yet so i will update you once i debug the code

Comment: In windows we need to add curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); as extra and it will start working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That  doesn't look so bad at all.

One mistake: drop the `--data-binary`:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"command\":\"on\",\"level\":75,\"device_id\":738486}"); /* data goes here */
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, -1); /* curl uses strlen() to determine postfield-size */
```

This should make it work, otherwise the --data-binary was simply copied into the post data ;)

I assume you initialized `curl` correctly with `curl_easy_init` and just left that out in your snippet.

EDIT: Added `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE`

Comment: I tried removing --data-binary as per your suggestion but it is not working i tried using both PUT and POST.  i initialized curl with curl_easy_init

Comment: You don't need CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE; without it libcurl will set the size from the given string.

Comment: @DanielStenberg If it was set somewhere before, resetting it to -1 restores the behaviour you describe. That's why I included it. Especially, since the initialization-code of curl is not visible in the snippet

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to convert a curl command line to libcurl source code:

```
curl [all the options] --libcurl source.c
```

The **--libcurl source.c** part will generate your source code template with the options set as your curl command line did. That usually takes you almost home at once.

Comment: This is indeed a nifty feature. It probably wouldn't be too bad for the OP to find his mistake anyway.